# When to use (:method) or (&:method)

Tags: ruby

Why does: `respond_to?` in:

```
class Wolf
  def howl; end
end

Wolf.new.respond_to?(:howl) # => true
```

not require `&` while `map` in:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(&:to_i) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

does? Also, are there any technical names for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `:method`, you're using some nice syntactical sugar in ruby that creates a new [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) object. When you throw an ampersand before it (`&:method`), you're using another piece of sugar. This invokes the `to_proc` method on the symbol.

So, these two things are identical:

```
method_proc = &:method

sym = :method
method_proc = method.to_proc
```

What's the difference between that and the other usage? Well, `respond_to?` has a single argument -- a symbol. So we can pass `:method` and be all fine and dandy. (Interestingly, objects do respond to the method named `method`, but that's a far more confusing question).

By comparison, Enumerable's iterators (like `map`, `select`, etc) accept a block. When we pass a Proc, it is interpreted properly as that block. So, these two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
[1,2,3].map { |i| i.even? }
[1,2,3].map(&:even?)
```

---

This equivalence is a little confusing, because of course Symbol has no idea that there's an `even?` method somewhere. To play around with it, I used `evenproc = :even?.to_proc` to inspect the resulting proc. It's implemented in C (at least in MRI ruby), and isn't willing to give up its source. However, its [arity](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Proc.html#method-i-arity) is `-1`, which means that it accepts one optional arg. My best guess is that it does something like this:

```
def to_proc
  method_name = self.to_s
  ->(a) { a.send(method_name) }
end
```

I could dig further, but I think we've already gone way past the question. ;) Good luck!